# Linear conjugacy growth function

Tags: gr.group-theory

Is there a finitely **presented** group with exactly linear conjugacy growth which is not virtually cyclic?

Here, conjugacy growth function $c(n)$ counts the number of conjugacy classes in the $n$-ball, and it is exactly linear if $c(n) \sim An$ for some constant $A \in (0, \infty)$.

Note that by the proof of Corollary 2.5 in von Puttkamer-Wu's paper: Linear groups, conjugacy growth, and classifying spaces for families of subgroups (IMRN, 2019), this group has to be non-hyperbolic.

Comment: You might define the definition of conjugacy growth you're using? The number of conjugacy classes met by the $n$-ball? By $c(n)$ "exactly linear" you mean $c(n)/n$ is bounded away from both $0$ and $\infty$?

Comment: For a linear or virtually solvable f.g. group, having at most linear conjugacy growth is equivalent to being virtually cyclic.

Comment: Yes. This is what I meant. I edited the statement and clarified the definitions. One key part of this question is the inquiry of a finitely presented group (there indeed exist examples but finitely generated).

Comment: User dodd tells you in their answer that there's no known f.p. example. I believe it's correct. Probably all known examples of non-virtually-cyclic finitely presented groups have at least quadratic conjugacy growth (even if not always checked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conjugacy growth function $f(n)$ is the number of conjugacy classes intersecting a ball of radius $n$. So if you take Ivanov's or Osin's examples of finitely generated groups with finite number of conjugacy classes, the groups are not virtually cyclic, but the conjugacy growth function is constant. If you take the modification of Ivanov'a example $G=\langle a,b \rangle$ where $a$ is of infinite order and every element of $G$ is a conjugate of a power of $a$, then the growth function of that group is going to be linear. For references see [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-54/issue-1/On-the-conjugacy-growth-functions-of-groups/10.1215/ijm/1299679750.full?tab=ArticleFirstPage).

**Update** These examples are not finitely presented. There are no known finitely presented examples.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you be more explicit about why the group you suggested is finitely presented? It is known from Hull-Osin that finitely generated such groups exist (but seems that they are usually not finitely presented). Also, even though I am familiar with Guba-Sapir's paper that you recommended, it will be more helpful if you can point out a more explicit result or theorem from their paper.